# How to scrape Javascript rendered data?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I have been trying to scrape this page for a while now and no matter what I try I can't seem to get the table data. The closest I've gotten is the table headers and titles.

I've tried using PhantomJS, Selenium and other methods but I'm stuck.

Site: http://marketwatch.dfm.ae/?isRedirected=true

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'http://marketwatch.dfm.ae/?isRedirected=true'
r = Render(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(r.frame.toHtml()))
print soup
```

And I've tried this

```
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

PHANTOMJS_PATH='./phantomjs'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
browser.get('http://marketwatch.dfm.ae/')

# let's parse our html
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
# get all the table data
tabdata = soup.find_all('tr', {'id': 'mw'})

print tabdata
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: It looks like that table might be loaded in asynchronously, so if you're hitting that page and only scraping the initial HTML, you won't see the contents of that table. A quick inspection of the network tab in the browser shows me they have an API endpoint that can take a variety of "commands". I'm not sure if they document their API anywhere, but that might be worth looking in to rather than scraping HTML.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at the API calls maybe I'll get a hint, but they don't have any API documentation on their site.